# problem with python code of matrix mapping

Tags: python, image-processing

I need an array consisting of all ways to move from point 'p' to 'q' in a given matrix. [To find all 4-path of given image]

Rules for moving from 1 point to another is:

1. **Only move up, down, left, right**
2. **Only move on blocks which are represented by 'a' [see from "if path_type==4"]**

Here the code:

```
def find_path(I, x1,y1,x2,y2,V, path_type):
    lr=len(I) #length of row
    lc=len(I[1]) #length of column
    (a,b)=V 
    v=[i for i in range(a, b+1)]
    B=I #Binary array of {'a', 'b'}
    for i in range(lr): 
        for j in range(lc): 
            for k in v: 
                if I[i][j]==k:
                    B[i][j]='a'
                else: 
                    pass
            if B[i][j]!='a':
                B[i][j]='b'
            else: 
                pass 
    B[x2-1][y2-1]='q'
    #B is now a binary array of 'a' and 'b'
    i=x1-1
    j=y1-1 #Since our array's origin is at (0,0)
    Tp=[] 
    p=[(i, j)] #starting coordinate
    path='path'
    
    
    if path_type==4:
        if path!='no path': 
            #stopping coordinate
            if B[i][j]!='q':
                if i+1<lr and B[i+1][j]=='a':
                    i=i+1
                    print(i, p, "1")
                    p.append((i,j))
                    print(p)
                elif j+1<lc and B[i][j+1]=='a':
                    j=j+1
                    p.append((i, j))
                    print(p, 2)
                elif i-1>=0 and B[i-1][j]=='a':
                    i=i-1
                    p.append((i, j))
                elif j-1>=0 and B[i][j-1]=='a':
                    j=j-1 
                    p.append((i, j))
                else :
                    p=["no path"]
                    Tp.append(p)
                Tp.append(p)
    else :
        pass 
    return Tp 


I=[[1,0,3,2,4],[4,3,4,0,2],[2,2,1,3,0],[2,4,0,3,2],[3,2,4,1,0]]
x1=4 
y1=1 
x2=2
y2=5
V={4,2}
path_type=4 
A=find_path(I, x1,y1,x2,y2,V, path_type)
print(A)
```

**Help needed for:

1. The code stop at p=[(3,0),(4,0)]
2. How can i keep the code running till array Tp includes all possible path**

The code needs to be completed without any python module

Comment: If you don't set restrictions on the path, the number of possibilities will be huge. If you allow self-overlaps, that number is even infinite.

Comment: Can you advice on how i can prevent over-lap. For restriction i wanted to add it such that in case there is no path it will reset array Tp to ["no path"] but i cannot find a way to determine if there are possible paths or not

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

A simple procedure to find all paths must be recursive. Assume that the grid cells are either allowed (your 'a') or disallowed (for ease of implemntation, you can surround the grid with dummy forbidden cells.

Starting from the initial point p:

- if you reached the final point q, store the path; else
- mark the current point as disallowed;
- try all four neighbors in turn;

  - if a neighbor is allowed, move to that point and recurse;
- reset the current point as allowed.

Note that while you go, you need to keep trace of the path traversed so far, for example using a stack.